# How can I choose the data that I want to plot with a slider in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, uislider

I have data in the following shape:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI42u.png)

with non-integer(!) values and of course much bigger. 
I want to plot E(y), choosing the x where I want to plot with a slider. To be honest, I am not used very well to Matlab-GUIs, so maybe my problem is not very complicated or my code so far a little bit stupid.

```
enter code here

handles.figure = figure('Position',[100 100 500 500],'Units','Pixels');
handles.axes1 = axes('Units','Pixels','Position',[60,100,400,300]);
handles.Slider1 = uicontrol('Style','slider','Position',[60 20 400 50],'Min',minx,'Max',maxx,'Value', minx,'SliderStep',[0.1 0.1],'Callback',@SliderCallback);
handles.Edit1 = uicontrol('Style','Edit','Position',[250 450 100 20],'String','Update Me');
handles.Text1 = uicontrol('Style','Text','Position',[180 450 60 20],'String','Slider Value');

guidata(handles.figure,handles); 

function SliderCallback(x,y,E)

    handles = guidata(gcf);
    SliderValue = get(handles.Slider1,'Value');
    indices = find(abs(x-SliderValue)<0.3)
    imin = min(indices)
    imax = max(indices)
    set(handles.Edit1,'String',num2str(SliderValue));
    plot(y(imin:imax),E(imin:imax),'Parent',handles.axes1);
end
```

This produces an empty plot with a slider. I get the following error:

> Undefined operator '-' for input arguments of type
>   'matlab.ui.control.UIControl'.
>
> Error in LiveEditorEvaluationHelperESectionEval8ac6cc3c>SliderCallback
>   (line 15)
>           indices = find(abs(x-SliderValue)<0.3)
>
> Error while evaluating UIControl Callback.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? The code works if I produce some random data within the Callback-function where the slider just defines a parameter, but not if I try to call my measurement data defining indices with the slider.

Comment: As called by your program, your function `SliderCallback` receive the handle of the slider (`handles.Slider1`) as first argument, and assign that to `x`, which then cause problem because `x` is no more a vector of `double` but is now a graphic handle. We would need to see more of the program but I suspect that just changing the line where you define the callback might sort your problem. Replace the callback definition of the slider by `handles.Slider1=uicontrol('Style','slider',...,'Callback',@(s,e)SliderCallback(x,y,Z));`.

Comment: It works. You are my hero.